# Understanding proof regarding theorem of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have trouble understanding one inequality in a proof of Complex Analysis by Zakeri on Page 25.

Theorem states: If a holomorphic function $f$ maps the disk $\mathbb{D}(p,r)$(centered at p with radius r) into the disk $\mathbb{D}(q,R)$, then $|f^\prime(p)|\leq \frac{R}{r}$.
Now in the proof we take $0<s<r$ and define $g=f-q\implies g^\prime=f^\prime$;
$$|f^\prime(p)|=|g^\prime(p)|\leq\frac{1}{s}\sup_{|z-p|=s}|g(z)|\leq\frac{R}{r}$$, then we are done.

My confusion is at the above middle inequality since we $s>0$ not necessarily $s<1$, how can the middle inequality hold when $s>1$?

Many thanks for helps.

Comment: Did you try Cauchy Integral Formulas, then the usual estimate?

Comment: You take $s$ and fix it. Then you prove "the middle" inequality. Since it is true for every $s < r$ it is true for $r$ as well. In words, to be clear, technically speaking, your last  inequality is not true. But it holds for each $s < r$ i.e. left side $ <= \frac{R}{s}$ hence is must hold for $s=r$

Comment: For the final inequality: suppose $|g'(p)| > \sup/r > 0.\;\,$ There exists $s_o,\;\;\,0<s_o<r,\;\;\;|g'(p)| > \sup/s_o  > \sup/r.\;\;$ Now $|g'(p)|\leqslant\sup/s_o<|g'(p)|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|g^{(1)}(p)| \;=\; \left|\frac{1!}{2\pi i} \int_{|\zeta-p|=s}\frac{g(\zeta)}{(\zeta-p)^{1+1}} \,d\zeta\right|,$$

$$|g'(p)| \;\leqslant\; \frac{1}{2\pi} \left(\sup_{|z-p|=s} \left|\frac{g(z)}{(z-p)^{2}}\right|\right)  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left| (p+se^{i\theta})'\right| \,d\theta,$$

$$|g'(p)| \;\leqslant\; \frac{1}{2\pi s^2} \left(\sup_{|z-p|=s}  |g(z)| \right)  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left| ise^{i\theta}\right| \,d\theta,$$

$$|g'(p)| \;\leqslant\; \frac{1}{2\pi s} \left(\sup_{|z-p|=s}  |g(z)| \right)  \int_{0}^{2\pi} 1 \,d\theta.$$